# Microsoft Excel latest updates (Version 1902 Build 11328.20512) has broken Querytables vba. Code is working in previous versions

Tags: excel, vba

```
url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp"
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Sheets("Data").Range("C1:AA200").Clear
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & url, Destination:=ws.Range("C1"))
  .BackgroundQuery = True
  .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'Here Code is getting stuck
  .SaveData = True
End With
```

Is anyone else facing the same issue after updates ? Also is there any alternative to get data from web into excel

Comment: Is the code **still working today** in previous versions? Or did it just work some time ago before you updated? I ask this because maybe something on that website has changed and that is the cause of the break (and you wrongly assume it was the Excel update).

Comment: Yes code with same website still works in excel 2013 and 2007. I tested on other machines which are having older versions. It is only not working with latest version.

Comment: I also noticed , Excel connectivity feature which lets use fetch data from Web under Data Tab> Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web has also stopped working in this version .

Comment: I can confirm that Excel hangs up on the `.Refresh`. But it seems just to be an incombatibility with that website. The feature works on other sites.

Comment: Is there any alternative method to get data from this source into excel

Comment: Best would be to use the API if this website provides one. Any other method might fail if they change something on their website and you have no influence on that. You can also scrap the HTML using Internet Explorer in VBA (google for tutorials about how to scrap websites with VBA and IE). But note that this will easily break if they change something on their website. The best and most reliable method is the API, ask them if there exists one.